# Test zero for 4 bytes in an int

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit

I come here to ask for tricks. I've got a 32-bit integer (that's 4 bytes). I want to test zero for each byte, and return true if one of them is true.

E.g.

```
int c1 = 0x01020304
cout<<test(c1)<<endl; // output false
int c2 = 0x00010203
cout<<test(c2)<<endl; // output true
int c3 = 0xfffefc00
cout<<test(c3)<<endl; // output true
```

Are there any tricks to do it in the least number of CPU cycles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways in the famous [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) page

```
bool hasZeroByte(unsigned int v)
{
    return ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F);
}
```

or

```
bool hasZeroByte = ((v + 0x7efefeff) ^ ~v) & 0x81010100;
if (hasZeroByte) // or may just have 0x80 in the high byte
{
  hasZeroByte = ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F);
}
```

And the likely most compact way when compiling to assembly

```
#define haszero(v) (((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)
```

As they're tricks, they're hard to understand so if you want clarity, mask out each byte and check like in dasblinkenlight's answer

[Example assembly output on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5ACNUqBgGoETQQC1MxVDwCeBTLQgiWgvMBaZ0ivCwKKAbgEoOABgCCHAOx93iv4uJMAjEWRQA/KCh7RW4ANkUXAA9PADFU9JTHGN4E5LT81KyvAGEHIs9SpIyM5wBmHw9PABFXD3c5BWVVDS1dfS4jEzMLKxs7J1avBv9FDqUVdU1tPUwY2qbFKOyeXM9MADMDg/2igFZscKds%2BKSADloXB4eXDnrWmbx9zYWe5f0sgD0AMUJEUAFsmDpFFQRII7Cp7Ks7i5rKECAhVggzAhZit3v4pviZn4fks%2BqtXhsIpFonFdgV8kUclUGYUYhUyuzKnlqplXtMCc0iQEgiEuoteni3u4vC0Ze15PNumSVrVBqZzJZUeNnDLvMLAsFiKEaVkALS5R5Wp4AVQAMkz4hErnTkbcXO73fa6g1ZZMFZ1SZL9OrhlqxooWOUBX5DWKwJBQq7Ei5U2mUnzfMS/CUSooExAk1wbin0ylU7q3NmcxU8wWiyXUxm0y5K9WuXXE9dcs2W63%2BZMhe4pI5GNJTlJSCxpC5J6hpMV%2BPxFMIxBJsrVaJOCDOR6OANZ0U4AOi4twALLQzy4uC4AJyPWqeLhjqTnyfTqSz0jzqSTwQgC4pA7l%2BI6kHAsBIGgYIAA54AwmjkJQ0FwQhxAgMAd70Ps8H6MQAEQDIu6kDINhMMQOjSFupDQWCmC2AA8iwDCUaBpBYBCbAIcR%2BCBMgBB4IiAFsZgiSYMgIj6FRk5jJgDDEQweAyMQ5E6MUGCSFI1EEMQeBgtJo7MGwKBLrwjBKQBkCjqgMECagJjSGaDG1P%2BojiJItCGeOH7Eb%2BiS3LEZqxOeijAMgyCKHex60JsuCEKC3CbqQijqbB8GaBunkpaZPDbruo4QFBqBpWhSEQCh6XocgRnAO6QE4QweEEURbGkSwqnSTRxV0YxzGsd%2BHGsMA3Fsbx4kCUJxGieJkmadRsnyWxinKap6lYJ1Ol6QZjBDSZvD8OZMiWRA1m2Xg9nCU5LlCG5Eh0F5UgTlOvnSP5gXBYo1VDYotzHi4f2xfgRDEJlyWpahGWJVwWSLvtvB5aBBVFSViEUOVxUQ%2BheDhbQWGkA1TWUC135tR1WmTrR9EEExLE8ZgnHDZpA14HxE2YMJ37TRJUnk%2BQthyQpSkqRRa1zduun6eThm7ZwcMCMtx2nXZDlSFdrlrh5D1PZ%2B35%2BQFQUhdjEW4390WA/FIOJfQKUY5VG7njDOUI7OSMoLbpVoxVaEgPYyAwTBAD69i4wHXBcAHiTBfjuGaM1xGkxRnWU71tOjfTQ0jczrOCezU1idzYt8/oi3fstwtqRpG0S9tNV7XwZkK/ASvnQ5AIMS%2Bq7ufdr7ay9UiRyFYKCL7Dgm2H5vA6DNso5bXC1LUjty87e6kIeF7Hp4tCnLcm93p4D53gFL6Le%2BpD6c8z1sb%2B/4gC%2BIEuw9XA%2BVf0jL44o6IvhLcgOeQA%3D)

Answer (score 3):

You can test it by masking each of the bytes in an `&` operation, and comparing the result to zero:

```
bool hasZeroByte(int32_t n) {
    return !(n & 0x000000FF)
        || !(n & 0x0000FF00)
        || !(n & 0x00FF0000)
        || !(n & 0xFF000000);
}
```

Comment: This may not be the fastest way because of `||`, which requires branching. You may want to play around with this in a small benchmark, and see if replacing `||` with `|` would provide any benefit.

Comment: isn't `~&` actually `^`?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to do this is probably to use `strnlen`, since most compilers will have optimized this to use low level instructions for finding zero bytes in strings.

```
bool hasZeroByte(int32_t n) {
    return strnlen(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n), 4) < 4;
}
```

If you want to be a little more explicit, you could use the `memchr` function which is documented to do exactly what you are asking:

```
bool hasZeroByte(int32_t n) {
    return memchr(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&n), 0, 4) != nullptr;
}
```

For those who don't believe this answer, feel free to take a look at the [`glibc` implementation of `strlen`](http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html) and see that it is already doing all of the mentioned bit twiddling tricks in the other answers.

See also:

- http://www.strchr.com/optimized_strlen_function
- http://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2
- http://www.int80h.org/strlen/

Comment: This doesn't make use of SSE2 or AVX to speed up string operations. And it contains a lot of logic compared to many other ways so it might not be faster for this simple case. Moreover it's `strlen`, not `strnlen`